# How to move a scroll bar canvas/frame without making the scroll bar grey

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I am currently programming something for my Computing coursework and I am trying to incorporate scroll bars into it, at the moment I cannot find any website which really explains why after moving the frame of the window, the scroll bar stops working (becomes grayed out) and after moving the canvas of the window, the canvas becomes really small (not the size I want it to be anyway). Here's some example code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
master.geometry("800x600+300+150")


class Example(tk.Frame):
def main(self):

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.hsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)

    self.populate()

def populate(self):
    vars1 = StringVar()
    vars1.set("junk")
    for i in range(100):
        tk.Entry(self.frame, text=vars1).grid(row=1*i, column=1)

def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

dave3 = Example()
dave3.main()


button = Button(master, text="Hi").place(x=0, y=0)

mainloop()
```

if I try to move the frame or canvas things happen that I don't want to, I just literally want the entire frame to move down so that the button does not overlap the canvas Entries and for the scroll bar to still work. If anyone can give a solution to this I would be extremely grateful, cheers.

P.s thanks to Bryan Oakley for getting me this far with his example code.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the frame or canvas"? Do you mean you are simply giving it different pack options, or giving it a different parent? Doing either of those shouldn't affect scrollbars at all.

Comment: Sorry I'm relatively new to Python so I'm not entirely fluent in the technical jargon associated with it, I basically want the scrollbar region to only be a small amount of the screen, like a window inside a window. In my actual project I have a menubar at the top and I would like the entire scrollbar region to be under that, not on top of it. Here if I try to use ".place" with the frame it grays out the scroll bars and renders them useless so my question is, what do I have to do to move the frame beneath the example button "Hi" and still have the scrollbars working? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

OK never mind I just figured it out, what I needed to do was create another frame and put the previous frame inside that one. After this I just configured that frame to the size I needed it to be. For any other newbies here's the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("800x600+300+150")

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def main(self):

        self.framee = tk.Frame(master,background="red")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.framee, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.hsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
        self.framee.place(x=0, y=50, width=500, height=500)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        vars1 = StringVar()
        vars1.set("junk")
        for i in range(100):
            tk.Entry(self.frame, text=vars1).grid(row=1*i, column=1)

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

dave3 = Example()
dave3.main()


button = Button(master, text="Hi").place(x=0, y=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are just now learning Tkinter, I strongly encourage you to use pack or grid instead of place. Those two make it much easier to make GUIs that are easy to maintain and have proper resize behavior. Place is generally only good for some very specific situations.